# how can i get 2d array by JSONArray in getting array from php?

Tags: android

this is in my activity for getting 2d array

```
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                
                //what to do here
                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            }
        }
    };
```

getting this value of "response" on calling it: (i edited this one)
use JSONArray in this code

```
{
   "0":[],
   "success":[true],
   "question":{
      "1":"question3",
      "2":"question1",
      "3":"question4"
   },
   "optiona":{
      "1":"optiona",
      "2":"optiona",
      "3":"optiona"
   },
   "optionb":{
      "1":"optionb",
      "2":"optionb",
      "3":"optionb"
   },
   "optionc":{
      "1":"optionc",
      "2":"optionc",
      "3":"optionc"
   },
   "optiond":{
      "1":"optiond",
      "2":"optiond",
      "3":"optiond"
   },
   "correct":{
      "1":"optiona",
      "2":"optionb",
      "3":"optiona"
   }
}
```

want to make arrays like (in android):-

> Arrayquestion=["question1","question2","question3"]
>
> Arrayoptiona=["optiona","optiona","optiona"]
>
> Arrayoptionb=["optionb","optionb","optionb"]
>
> Arrayoptionc=["optionc","optionc","optionc"]
>
> Arrayoptiond=["optiond","optiond","optiond"]
>
> Arraycorrect=["optiona","optionb","optiona"]
>
> success=[true]

Comment: Can you remove the json image and replace it with a code block?

Comment: done please see the response now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(string);
String[] question = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("question"));
String[] optiona = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("optiona"));
String[] optionb = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("optionb"));
String[] optionc = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("optionc"));
String[] optiond = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("optiond"));
String[] correct = readJsonObject(jsonResponse.getJSONObject("correct"));
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
```

And helper method:

```
private String[] readJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        String[] result = new String[3];
        result[0] = jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(1));
        result[1] = jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(2));
        result[2] = jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(3));
        return result;
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still getting the error ;( please check the question again i edited

Comment: @SumitYadav which line has error? Could you send stack trace?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"1":"question3","2":"question1","3":"question5"} at question of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray                       //using only one code for check, it runs the catch(JSONException e)

Comment: @SumitYadav thank you, I updated the answer. Could you check again?

Comment: dude you are awesome

Comment: please explain this:  String[] result = new String[3];
        result[0] = jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(1)); _/\_